# POST form to FormSubmit with HttpClient and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, post, form-submit, angular-httpclient

[FormSubmit](https://formsubmit.io/) is super great for easy lightweight form submission. I am using it in my Angular app and attempting to POST the form with the `HttpClient`, but I just can't seem to get it right. I am guessing my POST url is wrong but I am at a loss figuring out what the correct method is.

Here is my the `onSubmit` function:

```js
  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.contactForm.invalid) {
      return;
    } else {
        this.formSubmit.sendForm(JSON.stringify(this.contactForm.value));
    }
  }
```

Here the `HttpClient` service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FormsubmitService {
  constructor(
    public httpClient: HttpClient
  ) { }

  sendForm(formData) {
    console.log('Form Data:', formData);
    this.httpClient.post('https://formsubmit.io/send/<TOKEN HERE>', formData)
      .subscribe(
        (response) => console.log("Response:", response), (error) => console.log("Error:", error));
  }
}
```

Error response:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you use the angular service it will serialize the value for you. Read the documentation : https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Comment: you don't need to stringify the form value

Comment: @GérômeGrignon Thank you! But either way, then its an Object that sends but the error response persist :/

Comment: Why was I voted down for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day!
Can you try it out?

```
onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;
  if (this.contactForm.valid) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const { value } = this.contactForm;
    for (const key in value) {
      formData.append(key, value[key]);
    }

    this.formSubmit.sendForm(formData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Still nothing and FormData Object is returned empty.